# Javascript calc based on number choice - HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display a different option for different menu choices. 
If MenuNo1 (textinput) = either 1,2,3,4 or 5 - then the value of menuPrice1, should be R70.00
If MenuNo1(textinput) = either 8,9,12 - then the value of menuPrice1, should be R85.00
If MenuNo1 (textinput) = 11 - then the value of menuPrice1, should be R105.00

I have tried doing it this way:

> ```
> function calcMenu(form) {
> var MenuPrice1 = (+form.MenuPrice1.value);
> var MenuNo1 = (+form.MenuNo1.value);
>
> if ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
>     MenuPrice1.value = "70";
> } 
> else if ([8,9,12].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
>     MenuPrice1.value = "85";
> }
> else if (+form.MenuNo1.value == 11)  {
>     MenuPrice1.value = "105";    }  }
> ```

but I'm sure there is something incorrect on my code

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `||` OR Operator

```
if (+form.MenuNo1.value === '8' || 
    +form.MenuNo1.value === '9' || 
    +form.MenuNo1.value === '12' )
```

Also you need to use the == or === to check to see if it is equal to

Answer (score 2):

```
function calcMenu(form) {
    if ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
        MenuPrice1.value = "70";
    } 
    else if ([8,9,12].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
        MenuPrice1.value = "85";
    }
    else if (+form.MenuNo1.value == 11)  {
        MenuPrice1.value = "105";
   } 
}
```

You can see an example of the indexOf method working in this way here: http://jsfiddle.net/fHzEG/

Comment: That won't work, as you are casting the value to an integer, but checking against strings. You did it right in the fiddle. :)

Comment: @ChrisDixon Thank you. I am getting this error in the console? `MenuPrice1 is not defined`

Comment: Then that's probably due to the scope of your MenuPrice1 variable, where are you declaring this? Please put in your question.